# LibGDX - make actors fill the parent horizontally

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I can't figure out how to make a jrpg-like menu with LibGDX.
I have all the elements I need, a hero picture, a verticalGroup with hero stats and a third verticalGroup which currently only holds a test button.

The problem is that the elemens are really small, I would like for them to spread out across the whole width evenly divided.

[game screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p61AX.jpg)

```
package com.mygdx.game.UI;

import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.TextureRegionDrawable;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Align;
import com.mygdx.game.Entities.Entity;
import com.mygdx.game.Map.Map;

import Utility.Utility;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.HorizontalGroup;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.VerticalGroup;

public class BottomMenu extends Window {
    private static final String TAG = BottomMenu.class.getSimpleName();

    private static String title = "";
    private String unknownHeroImageLocation = "sprites/gui/portraits/unknown.png";

    private Image heroImage;

    //identifier labels
    private Label hpLabel;
    private Label mpLabel;
    private Label xpLabel;
    private Label levelLabel;
    private Label iniLabel;

    //value labels
    private Label hp;
    private Label mp;
    private Label xp;
    private Label levelVal;
    private Label iniVal;
    private Label heroNameLabel;

    private Entity linkedEntity;

    private static final float BOTTOMMENUHEIGHTTILES = 6;
    private static final float BOTTOMMENUWIDGETS = 3;


    //Attributes
    private int heroLevel;
    private int heroHP;
    private int heroMP;
    private int heroXP;
    private int heroINI;


    private HorizontalGroup bottomMenuTable;

    public BottomMenu(Entity[] entities){
        super(title, Utility.STATUSUI_SKIN);

        linkUnitsToMenu(entities);
        initElementsForUI();
        configureElements();
        addElementsToWindow();
    }

    private void linkUnitsToMenu(Entity[] entities) {
        for(Entity entity : entities) {
            entity.setbottomMenu(this);
        }
    }

    private void initElementsForUI() {
        this.debug();
        //hero name
        heroNameLabel = new Label("", Utility.STATUSUI_SKIN, "inventory-item-count");
        heroNameLabel.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        heroNameLabel.setScale(20.0f);

        changeHeroImage(unknownHeroImageLocation);

        //groups
        bottomMenuTable = new HorizontalGroup();
        //bottomMenuTable.align(Align.center);
        bottomMenuTable.setFillParent(true);
        this.setTransform(true);
        this.setPosition(0, 0);

        //labels
        hpLabel = new Label(" hp:", Utility.STATUSUI_SKIN);
        hp = new Label("", Utility.STATUSUI_SKIN);
        mpLabel = new Label(" mp:", Utility.STATUSUI_SKIN);
        mp = new Label("", Utility.STATUSUI_SKIN);
        xpLabel = new Label(" xp:", Utility.STATUSUI_SKIN);
        xp = new Label("", Utility.STATUSUI_SKIN);
        levelLabel = new Label(" lv:", Utility.STATUSUI_SKIN);
        levelVal = new Label("", Utility.STATUSUI_SKIN);
        iniLabel = new Label(" ini:", Utility.STATUSUI_SKIN);
        iniVal = new Label("", Utility.STATUSUI_SKIN);
    }

    private void changeHeroImage(String heroImageLink) {
        Utility.loadTextureAsset(heroImageLink);
        TextureRegion tr = new TextureRegion(Utility.getTextureAsset(heroImageLink));
        TextureRegionDrawable trd = new TextureRegionDrawable(tr);
        if(heroImage != null) {
            trd.setMinHeight(this.getHeight());
            trd.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() / BOTTOMMENUWIDGETS);
            heroImage.setDrawable(trd);
        }else {
            trd.setMinHeight(this.getHeight());
            trd.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() / BOTTOMMENUWIDGETS);
            heroImage = new Image(trd);
        }
    }

    private void configureElements() {
        defaults().expand().fill();
    }

    private void addElementsToWindow() {
        this.add(bottomMenuTable);

        bottomMenuTable.addActor(heroImage);
        heroImage.debug();

        Table statsGroup = new Table();

        statsGroup.setHeight(this.getHeight());
        statsGroup.setWidth(this.getWidth() / BOTTOMMENUWIDGETS);

        statsGroup.add(heroNameLabel);
        statsGroup.row();

        statsGroup.add(hpLabel);
        statsGroup.add(hp);
        statsGroup.row();

        statsGroup.add(mpLabel);
        statsGroup.add(mp);
        statsGroup.row();

        bottomMenuTable.addActor(statsGroup);
        statsGroup.debug();

        VerticalGroup smallMenu = new VerticalGroup();

        smallMenu.setHeight(this.getHeight());
        smallMenu.setWidth(this.getWidth() / BOTTOMMENUWIDGETS);

        smallMenu.addActor(new TextButton("test", Utility.STATUSUI_SKIN));
        bottomMenuTable.addActor(smallMenu);
        smallMenu.debug();
    }

    public void setHero(Entity entity) {
        if(entity != null) {
            if(entity.getName() != heroNameLabel.getText().toString()) {
                this.linkedEntity = entity;
                initiateHeroStats();
                populateElementsForUI(entity);
            }
        }else {
            resetStats();
        }
    }

    private void initiateHeroStats() {
        heroLevel = this.linkedEntity.getLevel();
        heroHP = this.linkedEntity.getHp();
        heroMP = this.linkedEntity.getMp();
        heroXP = this.linkedEntity.getXp();
        heroINI = this.linkedEntity.getIni();
    }

    private void populateElementsForUI(Entity entity) {
        heroNameLabel.setText(entity.getName());
        changeHeroImage(entity.getPortraitPath());
        updateLabels();
    }

    private void resetStats() {
        heroNameLabel.setText("");
        hp.setText("");
        mp.setText("");
        xp.setText("");
        levelVal.setText("");
        iniVal.setText("");
        changeHeroImage(unknownHeroImageLocation);
    }

    public void update() {
        Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "updating bottom menu UI");
        updateStats();
        updateLabels();
        updateSize();
    }

    private void updateLabels() {
        hp.setText(String.valueOf(heroHP));
        mp.setText(String.valueOf(heroMP));
        xp.setText(String.valueOf(heroXP));
        levelVal.setText(String.valueOf(heroLevel));
        iniVal.setText(String.valueOf(heroINI));
    }

    private void updateStats() {
        if(linkedEntity != null) {
            heroLevel = linkedEntity.getLevel();
            heroHP = linkedEntity.getHp();
            heroMP = linkedEntity.getMp();
            heroXP = linkedEntity.getXp();

            if(linkedEntity.getEntityactor().getIsHovering()) {
                this.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateSize() {
        int scaledWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        int scaledHeight = (int) (BOTTOMMENUHEIGHTTILES * Map.TILE_HEIGHT_PIXEL);
        this.setSize(scaledWidth,scaledHeight);
        bottomMenuTable.setSize(scaledWidth,scaledHeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using `lml` (LibGDX Markup Language based on XML)? Once you get used to it, it should speed things up and ease writing code. It will allow you to specify the appearance of your game and its behavior (similar to HTML and CSS - but it is not as powerful as these both). My respect for you that you have handled your (re)sizing and positioning manually in your code so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Change all your Vertical/HorizontalGroups to Tables.
- Check out the fillX/expandX methods on the Table's Cells.